# Quick onkeyup function

Tags: javascript

I am using onkeyup function in a textbox to make a button click but when I click on enter first on TextBox cursor moving to next line and then `onkeyup` function is taking place. For perfection in my project I need quick onkeyup function where cursor should not go down and function should take place. Just like StackOverflow's comment TextBox.

I am using following code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="inputmess" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="70px" Width="495px" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('sendmess').click()" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keydown` instead of `keyup` and `return false;`.

```
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13){ document.getElementById('sendmess').click(); return false;}"
```

Another alternative:

```
onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13){ document.getElementById('sendmess').click(); event.preventDefault();}"
```

A demo: http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/jCsY6/

Comment: That's not how SO behaves, though. And he'd like the same behavior.